# I could not manage to use Switch Component in LTspice

Tags: switches, ltspice, simulation

There is a circuit to control a pwm signal with a switch in Ltspice. But it does not switch of despite to off mode of controller voltage. Is there anyone to give me some suggestion.
My and gate specifications -> Vhigh=5 Vlow=0
My switch specifications -> .model SW SW(Ron=1 Roff=1Meg Vt=2.75)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just don't have your problems:

[image]

But since you provide no additional circuit details and have chosen to show only a little part, it's difficult to say much more.

The above is the ***complete*** circuit. And you can readily see that it behaves as expected. It shows Vhigh and Vlow. Yours does not. So all I have are your assurances. Not visible evidence. Similarly for your switch model. I have what you say. But I do not see what is actually being seen by LTspice. My example shows everything you need to see.

Provide fix this situation by showing everything pertinent to the question and perhaps something useful comes of it.

My netlist is as follows:

```
S1 B A P 0 MS1
V1 N001 0 PULSE(0 5 20u 1n 1n 5u 17u)
V2 A 0 PULSE(0 18 0 50n 50n 15u 40u) AC 1
R1 B 0 1k
A1 N001 0 0 0 0 0 P 0 BUF Vhigh=5 Vlow=0
.model MS1 SW(Ron=.1 Roff=100Meg Vt=2.75)
.tran 0 300u 0 1n
```

Comment: Ah bro, the resistor R1 solve the problem for me.. Thank you so much